# Javascript in Chrome cannot handle date in the format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime

Using chrome's js console, I cannot seem to get it to recognize dates formatted in dd/mm/yyyy

```
> +new Date()
1369840513437
> +new Date("5/28/2013")
1369717200000
> +new Date("28/5/2013")
NaN
```

The clients computer is in Canada and the regional settings are correct. I've also added the language preference to chrome settings. The above code works as expected in both IE and FF (edit: IE and FF give a number but not the correct number). What an I missing?

Comment: The `Date` constructor can only parse certain formats. Read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate

Comment: ... because there's no way to know whether `1/2/2013` is Jan 2nd or Feb 1st.

Comment: Imagine a situation where you have two dates `6/5/2013` vs. `5/6/2013`. The constructor doesn't know which one you would actually want to use. So it only understands mm/dd/yyy in this case and you have to follow the rules.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's doing what you expect in FF/IE. `new Date("28/5/2013")` produces the date `April 5th, 2015` in IE, because it assumes you mean the 28th month of this year, which is the 4th month of 2015 (with carrying). So it's still doing `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there's not much you can do other than split it up and put it back together, unless you want to use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Bare in mind, this works if you're always expecting the format to be `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
var result = "28/5/2013".split("/");
var mydate = new Date(parseInt(result [2], 10),
                  parseInt(result [1], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(result [0], 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const result = (date: string): string => {
        const [month, day, year] = date.split('/');
        return `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
    };
```

This is also another solution.